# Expo keep on breaking without any warning or error after build

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, android-studio, expo

I am a beginner at react-native stuff pardon me if the issue is not complex. I set up the environment of react-native in the expo app but the app keeps on breaking without any warning or error. It was working before in my smartphone but after using an android studio it keeps on breaking. Now, both in the emulator and smartphone. Thank you in advance!
During Build:
[image]
After Build:
[image]

Comment: see your device logs: https://docs.expo.io/workflow/logging/#view-logs-from-android-device-or-emulator